# What do we call the changes of acceleration?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, terminology, jerk

Our teacher told it but I don't remember the name of acceleration changes?

I mean the differental of displacement-acceleration equation what does it give to us?

Comment: Jerk https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)  at least I think that's what you mean, changes of acceleration with respect to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time rate of change of acceleration is called the jerk $j$.  And analogous to force $F=m\cdot a$  we have the yank $Y=m\cdot j$.  The next three derivatives have been called several things.  I had one mentor that wanted them to be zip, pop, and go.  I have also seen snap, crackle, and pop.